# Python list to list of map

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

ENV: python 3.7+, boto3

I have list of private IP address ['10.0.3.11', '10.0.2.22']

```
response = route53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
           HostedZoneId="ABDCEFGH",
           ChangeBatch={
               'Comment': 'Dns to ec2 instance',
               'Changes': [
                   {
                       'Action': 'UPSERT',
                       'ResourceRecordSet': {
                           'Name': "ts-uat",
                           'Type': 'A',
                           'TTL': 120,
                           'ResourceRecords': [
                              {
                                   'Value': record['Value']
                              },
                          ]
                       }
                   }
               ]
           }
       )
```

How to get it as follows

```
            HostedZoneId="ABDCEFGH",
            ChangeBatch={
                'Comment': 'Dns to ec2 instance',
                'Changes': [
                    {
                        'Action': 'UPSERT',
                        'ResourceRecordSet': {
                            'Name': "ts-uat",
                            'Type': 'A',
                            'TTL': 120,
                            'ResourceRecords': [
                               {
                                   'Value': 10.0.3.11
                               },
                               {
                                   'Value': 10.0.2.22
                               },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        )
```

I tried the following

```
def getListofIP(n):
    return "{'value' : %s,}" %  (n) 
result = map(getListofIP, private_ip)
print(list(result))
```

output was

["{'value' : 10.0.3.11,}", "{'value' : 10.0.2.22,}"]

Comment: Do `return {'value' : n}` to return a dict instead of a string.

Comment: @WillRichardson , Absolutely correct it works. But, I  need it to be in [{'Value': '10.0.3.11'}, {'Value': '10.0.2.22'}]. So I did {'Value' : '{}'.format(n)}. Is that correct way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @WillRichardson. it works for me

```
def getListofIP(n):
    return {'Value' : '{}'.format(n)}

result = map(getListofIP, private_ip)
print(list(result))
```

Output

```
[{'Value': '10.0.3.11'}, {'Value': '10.0.2.22'}]
```